# Как подключить TCPDF к Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, tcpdf

Кто-нибудь подключал плагин TCPDF? Это плагин создает pdf документ. Я, вроде, подключил, но выдает ошибку

> TCPDF ERROR: Some data has already
>   been output, can't send PDF file.

Вроде как в ходе гугл поиска нашел, что надо проверять пустые строки или запущеные исполняемые файлы. Но страница запущена даже без подключения load.php. Я думаю, там ошибка в чем-то другом. Может, посоветуете, где искать или какую нибудь библиотеку. Мне надо создать файл и фоном загрузить изображение.  Ну а в идеале вообще редактировать pdf-файл.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нашел решение вопроса следующим образом. Добавил `ob_end_clean();` перед

```
if (@file_exists(dirname(__FILE__).'/lang/eng.php')) {
    require_once(dirname(__FILE__).'/lang/eng.php');
    $pdf->setLanguageArray($l);
}
```